# Url rewrite in IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, rewritemap

i have two seperate config files, which contains url reqwrite tags, i want to point these files to the web.config, under rewrite element, until i have one

```
<rewriteMaps configSource="VanityUrl\urls.config" />
```

if i add one more similar tag to point another file, it throws the 500 server error
can i add multiple rewriteMaps tag to point multiple files in web.config, or any alternate, the reason behind 2 seperate files are one is used for rewrite, and another for static redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple rewriteMaps tags will violate the web.config schema, so IIS won't let you do that.  I think you'll need to combine them, or do something clever to load them at runtime from your two separate configuration files.